# Running formula based on month of year

Tags: excel

New at this, but I'm trying to create formula to find month of year between cells C1 and N1 (formatted cells) based on current date, and subtract cell A2 from whatever the cell below the current month is to show on cell B2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a visual of what you're after, or at least some example ASCII-display of what's going on... a textual reference like this is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=HLOOKUP(MONTH(NOW()),C1:N2,2,0)-A2
```

(assumes formatting is of numbers to display as months, eg June entered as `6`).